# Angular create tabs views without loosing data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to create 3 tabs, every tab view has its own controller, but all of them connected one to each other.
I need the data to stay, when i move from tab to another and comeback, something like form fields texts or whatever.

The way i try to do this with ng-include and ng show but it doesnt work, the step two controller dosent run.

This is the main page, that start with step one:

```
<section class="step-one steps-container" ng-show="stepOneView">
        // step one content

        <button ng-click="goToStepTwo()">Next</button>

</section>

<div ng-include="'client/hunter/step-two.html'" ng-show="stepTwoView"></div>

<div ng-include="'client/hunter/step-three.html'" ng-show="stepThreeView"></div>
```

Step Two tpl -

```
<section ng-controller="stepTwoController">
 //content
</section>
```

Step One controller:

```
$scope.stepOneView = true;

$scope.goToStepTwo = function() {
 $scope.stepOneView = false; 
 $scope.stepTwoView = true;
}
```

Step Two controller -

```
console.log('Im in step two'); // This is not working
```

Comment: Store the data in the Service, or in a common scope.

Answer (score 0):

I would have have one main controller and then have one sub controller for each tab. The main controller would control which tab is visible using a $scope variable which keeps track of the current tab:

```
<body ng-Controller="MainCtrl">
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" ng-click="changeTab(1)">1</a>
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" ng-click="changeTab(2)">2</a>
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" ng-click="changeTab(3)">3</a>
    <div ng-include="'tab1.html'" ng-show="tab === 1"></div>
    <div ng-include="'tab2.html'" ng-show="tab === 2"></div>
    <div ng-include="'tab3.html'" ng-show="tab === 3"></div>
</body>
```

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.tab = 1;

  $scope.changeTab = function (tab) {
    $scope.tab = tab;
  };
});
```

tab1.html

```
<div ng-controller="Tab1Ctrl">
  <label>Tab1</label>
  <div>
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

tab1.js:

```
angular
  .module('plunker')
  .controller('Tab1Ctrl', function($scope) {
  });
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/iB6vhgIjT4fjYuBqVVS6?p=preview

As you can see in the demo if you enter some text in the textbox, switch tabs and then switch back the text remains.

Comment: Thats not solve my problem, because if i need to update property of service and then move to view two the property doesnt update. see plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/k60fXtzhDGM5XezZjPSC?p=preview

Comment: Are you saying that you want to update name in the service and then it persist between tabs?

Comment: Yes. thats what i want.

Comment: Why not just use the controllerAs syntax and then you don't need to use a service: http://plnkr.co/edit/EgEQEPNN18NIFH92zIjw?p=preview